# How to find out which controls produced (how much) ViewState

Tags: asp.net, optimization, viewstate, webforms

For pages with a large ViewState, I'd like to find out by which controls the ViewState was produced (which control produced how much ViewState).

Are there any tools which allow displaying that information? What's the easiest way to find out?

**Update**: What I'm looking for / what would be very nice, is some plugin for FireBug or Fiddler, which could show information about which controls produced how much ViewState. Don't know if something like that exists.